# Why I Can't execute command to set environment variables in docker compose from command section

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to collect data relevent to AWS S3 and I want to store it in environment variables inside my container as above:

```yaml
version: '3.4'
    services:
        web:
            image: amazon/aws-cli:latest
            stdin_open: true # equivalent of -i
            tty: true        # equivalent of -t
            entrypoint: sh -c
            deploy:
                mode: replicated
                replicas: 1
                resources:
                    limits:
                        cpus: "2"
                        memory: 2048M
                restart_policy:
                    condition: on-failure
                    delay: 5s
                    max_attempts: 3
                    window: 120s
            environment:
                - HTTP_PROXY=PROXY:PORT
                - HTTPS_PROXY=PROXY:PORT
                - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=KEY
                - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=SECRET
                - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ZONE
            ports:
                - "8080:8080"
            command:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
                - |
                    cd /
                    cd usr/local/bin/
                    ./aws configure set aws_access_key_id $$KEY
                    ./aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $$SECRET
                    ./aws configure set region $$ZONE
                    SUM=$$(aws s3 ls  | wc -l)
                    tail -F anything
```

The problem is: when I run `printenv`, I could not found my `$SUM` environment variable.
Can you help me please understand this behavior ?

Comment: In which shell are you running `printenv`?

Comment: I am getting the id of the image from docker container command, I run after the exec command with sh parameters and I execute the printenv command

Comment: That's two different shells, you set the variable in one shell and try to check the value of the variable in a different shell.

Comment: okay, I understand now the reason. Is there another way to get the result from the command line and print it outside the container?

Comment: You could run the printenv as part of the container command (between the variable set and the tail command, and then check the container logs.